# Packet loss showing at point of entry onto network - what could cause?

Tags: networking, tcp, wireshark, cisco

A traffic source (server) with a 1gigabit NIC is attached to a 1gigabit port of a Cisco switch.

I mirror this traffic (SPAN) to a separate gigabit port on the same switch and then capture this traffic on a high throughput capture device (riverbed shark).
Wireshark analysis of the capture shows that there is a degree of packet loss - around 0.1% of TCP segments are being lost (based on sequence number analysis).

Given that this is the first point on the network for this traffic, what can cause this loss?
The throughput is not anywhere near 1gigabit, there are no port errors (which might indicate a dodgy patch lead).

In Richard Stevens illustrated TCP book he makes mention of 'local congestion' - where the TCP stack is producing data at a rate faster than the underlying local queues can be emptied.

Could this be what I am seeing?
If so, is there a way to confirm it on an AIX box?
(Stevens example used the Linux 'tc' command for a ppp0 device to demonstrate drops at the lower level)

Answer (score 0):

The lost can be anywhere along the network path.

If there is loss between two hosts, you should be seeing DUP ACKs. You need to see what side is sending the DUP ACKs. This would be the host that isn't receiving all the packets. ( When a packet is not seen, it will send a DUP ACK to ask for the packet again.)

There may be congestion somewhere else along the path. Look for output drops on interfaces. Or CRC erros .

Comment: I think my description was perhaps a bit lacking.

Comment: I think my description was perhaps a bit lacking. The capture is taken at the point where the source is putting traffic onto the network. Even though it is the first point on the network, the captures are showing that TCP segments are missing. The traffic is not passing through intervening switches and being dropped through congestion or qos rules - it is the very first point it gets out on the network. I do see the expected dup acks and retransmissions that are a consequence of loss - but am trying to figure out how packets could be lost so early in the journey.

Comment: I may have found my "lost" segments. In almost all cases, the "TCP previous segment lost" warning entry in the trace was followed within a few segments by a "TCP out of order" warning - which corresponded to the segment that had been considered missing. (I guess my next task will be to figure out why they are being sent out of order)

Comment: If segments are being lost, then you will also get out of order warnings....these are the lost segments being retransmitted. 

You need to sniff packets hop-by-hop towards the source of the out of order packets until you can see both the original packet and the out of order(retransmitted ) packet.

This would then be the last devices that sees the original packet.

Comment: thanks - i can't sniff hop-by-hop though as it is the first hop that the "loss" is present at. having had a closer look i can see that in most cases the out-of-order segment isn't the result of a *re*transmission - in most cases the sender is sending the packet before receiving the three DUP ACKs that would initiate a fast retransmit - which seems to indicate that the "segment shuffling" is occurring at point of origin - rather than as a result of the usual segment recovery mechanisms.